# HTML nested div tags break my first button

Tags: html

First button seems to break and i can't figure out what i did wrong. All seems in order to me.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4"
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-info">Info</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nvm found my error

Answer (score 1):

You haven't closed the second `div` opening tag. Also you need to close the `row` div.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-4"> <!-- Close this tag -->
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-info">Info</button>
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Like</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-info">Info</button>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

You haven't completed `div` tag. Along with that You have to close `row` class `div`

Hope this helps.